# Windows Phone development tools

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I have installed vs-2013 and install Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC Windows Phone 8.1 development using this link https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk and after that I want to install    sdk 8.0 using the above link but it gets me error below:

```
This Product can only be installed on Windows 8 or later 64-bit Machine.
```

But I have already installed windows 8

Kindle suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: So you are using a 32-bit Windows 8 then?

Comment: So, what should I do because I have already install vs 2013 Is there any way to upgrade 32 bit to 64 bit

Comment: Not sure, but pretty sure you will need a clean install.

Comment: I am uninsatall vs2013 and after that install vs 2012 and sdk-8.0 on my 32 bit win 8.

Comment: No, Windows 8 64-bit as it says on the box. Start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download suggests the requirement for Windows 8 (x64) as does the Introducing Windows Phone SDK 8.0 blog.  See: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307 (Expand System Requirements) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-windows-phone-sdk-8-0.aspx